# How to override/modify the Content property of Frame to accept multiple Views in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, contentproperty

Here's the **C#** template code I have:

```
public class PopupFrame : Frame
{
    public PopupFrame()
    {
        this.SetDynamicResource(BackgroundColorProperty, "PopUpBackgroundColor");
        this.SetDynamicResource(CornerRadiusProperty, "PopupCornerRadius");
        HasShadow = true;
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        Padding = 0;
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
    }
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
<t:PopupFrame>
   <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
         <t:PopupHeader Text="Copy Deck" />
         <t:PopupEntryHeader Text="New Deck Name" />
                
                More XAML here
   </StackLayout>
</t:PopupFrame>
```

Is there some way that I can code `PopupFrame` so that the `StackLayout` is part of it and it takes content.

Here's what I would like to code:

```
<t:PopupFrame>
   <t:PopupHeader Text="Copy Deck" />
   <t:PopupEntryHeader Text="New Deck Name" />
                
       More XAML here

</t:PopupFrame>
```

Comment: Unfortunately you have to use a stacklayout inside frame if you want to use inside frame more than one object on Xamarin Forms. But why do you use two stacklayout? It is not necessary.

Comment: Maybe you could look at [contentview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If i am right, you could achieve this by setting the `ContentProperty` attribute to your `PopupFrame` class to a property that is itself a collection. This would override the `ContentProperty` of `Frame` which is `Content` to allow you to set multiple views as the contents instead of just one which is the default for Frame...

So, if all this sounds good to you, keep on reading.

### The HowTo

You could define a `ContentProperty` for your `PopupFrame` class, like this:

```cs
[Xamarin.Forms.ContentProperty("Contents")]
class PopupFrame : Frame
{
    StackLayout contentStack { get; } = new StackLayout();

    public IList<View> Contents { get => contentStack.Children; }


    public PopupFrame()
    {
        Content = contentStack;

        HasShadow = true;
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        Padding = 0;
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
    }
}
```

Then your are able to do something like what you want:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:t="clr-namespace:popupframe"
             x:Class="popupframe.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <t:PopupFrame>
            <t:PopupHeader Text="Test header"/>
            <Label Text="Test content"/>
        </t:PopupFrame>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Which on my side works showing both the `PopupHeader` and the `Label`:

[image]

### And finally a bit of theory on ContentProperty

What follows is taken literally from the [book of Ch. Petzold on Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/).

Every class used in **XAML** is allowed to define one property as a content property (sometimes also called the class’s default property). For this content property, the property-element tags are not required, and any XML content within the start and end tags is automatically assigned to this property. Very conveniently, the content property of `ContentPage` is `Content`, the content property of `StackLayout` is `Children`, and the content property of `Frame` is `Content`.

These content properties are documented, but you need to know where to look. A class specifies its content property by using the ContentPropertyAttribute. If this attribute is attached to a class, it appears in the online Xamarin.Forms API documentation along with the class declaration. Here’s how it appears in the documentation for `ContentPage`:

```
[Xamarin.Forms.ContentProperty("Content")]
public class ContentPage : TemplatedPage
```

If you say it aloud, it sounds a bit redundant: "The Content property is the content property of ContentPage."

The declaration for the `Frame` class is similar:

```
[Xamarin.Forms.ContentProperty("Content")]
public class Frame : ContentView
```

`StackLayout` doesn’t have a `ContentProperty` attribute applied, but `StackLayout` derives from `Layout<View>`, and `Layout<T>` has a `ContentProperty` attribute:

```
[Xamarin.Forms.ContentProperty("Children")]
public abstract class Layout<T> : Layout, IViewContainer<T>
where T : View
```

The `ContentProperty` attribute is inherited by the classes that derive from `Layout<T>`, so `Children` is the content property of `StackLayout`.

Answer (score 5):

**PopupFrame.cs**

```
public class PopupFrame : Frame
{
    StackLayout PopupContent;
    public IList<View> Body
    {
        get => PopupContent.Children;
    }
    public PopupFrame()
    {

        PopupContent = new StackLayout();

        SetDynamicResource(Frame.BackgroundColorProperty, "PopUpBackgroundColor");
        SetDynamicResource(Frame.CornerRadiusProperty, "PopupCornerRadius");
        HasShadow = true;
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        Padding = 0;
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;

        Content = PopupContent;
    }
```

**Now you can use**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:t="clr-namespace:popupframe"
             x:Class="popupframe.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
       <t:PopupFrame>
         <t:PopupFrame.Body>
             <t:PopupHeader Text="Test header"/>
             <Label Text="Test content"/>
           </t:PopupFrame.Body>
        </t:PopupFrame>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```