# Content in a complex Xamarin Forms custom control

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a custom control by deriving from `ContentView`. My goal is to have a user consume the class as you would expect to consume any control with a single piece of content:

```xaml
<local:NewControl>
  <Image source="..." />
</local:NewControl>
```

However, I would like the control to contain a grid and then have the content placed in the grid. Conceptually (i.e. ignoring the fact that `ContentPresenter` cannot be used in this way), I'd like `NewControl.xaml` to look like this:

```xaml
<ContentView ...>
  <Grid x:Name="HiddenGrid">
    <ContentPresenter />
  </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

Doing what I detailed above results in `HiddenGrid` being replaced by the `Image`, rather than the image being inserted in the visual tree as a child of the `ContentPresenter`.

At the moment, I'm achieving my goal by deriving from `Grid` instead of `ContentView`, but I'd like to hide this implementation detail so consumers cannot interfere with the `Grid` and have a control to which they can assign only a single piece of content.

This seems like it should be straightforward (and widely applicable to all sorts of scenarios where content needs to be embellished in some way), but I can't see a way of doing it. Am I missing something obvious, is it not possible, or is it just tricky to do and I need to read up on something (like control templates)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use ControlTemplate. Xamarin.Forms control templates enable to define the visual structure of ContentView derived custom controls, and ContentPage derived pages.

```
<ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Text="Test" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"></ContentPresenter>

            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
        
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
```

**Xaml**

```
<local:NewControl>
  <Label Text= "Test"/>
</local:NewControl>
```

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I wanted. It's worth noting that the controls in the Template aren't visible in the usual way within the control's cs file and to access `HiddenGrid` in my example, something like the following is necessary: `Grid HiddenGrid => (Grid)GetTemplateChild("HiddenGrid");`

Answer (score 4):

One way i can think of is overriding the `ContentProperty` of your `NewControl`: by doing this you can control exactly what happens with the "Content" of the `NewControl`.

To do this follow the next steps:

- Define your control's appearance in **Xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HiddenGridTest.NewControl">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="HiddenGrid" Padding="20">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**Very important** here is that you put your `Grid` inside the `Content` property explicitly!

```xml
<ContentView.Content>
</ContentView.Content>
```

- Override the `ContentProperty` of your control and link it to the `Children` of the `HiddenGrid`

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace HiddenGridTest
{
    [ContentProperty("Contents")]
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewControl : ContentView
    {

        public IList<View> Contents { get => HiddenGrid.Children; }

        public NewControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

- Consume your `NewControl`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HiddenGridTest"
             x:Class="HiddenGridTest.MainPage">

    <local:NewControl>
        <Label  Text="Inside grid"
               BackgroundColor="Red"/>
    </local:NewControl>
    
</ContentPage>
```

The result is shown in the image below. Note that the image is set as content of the `Grid` (occupying the first row and first column!):

[image]

---

Interestingly enough, i also answered a couple of questions this week where also overriding the `ContentProperty` was useful. Since they could complete the information posted in this answer, i leave the links here:

- [How to override/modify the Content property of Frame to accept multiple Views in Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64874158/7432242)
- [How can I combine XAML and a template into one C# template with Rg.Plugins.Popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64999117/7432242)

Comment: Not quite the right fit for my use case, but +1 for the knowledge about the `ContentProperty` attribute - I didn't know that existed (although it obviously makes sense there is some mechanism for determining which property XAML children are assigned to). It could be useful in future!